# Image Box-Shadow Positioning

Tags: html, css

I want my screen to have this box-shadow property so there's a box with all the content inside of the screen. I also want to place an image as the landing section and the image will pulsate then fade into the rest of the web page. I cannot get the image to center in the box I have created.

Not sure how to do this

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
  height: auto;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 30px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -30px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#landing {
  background: white;
}

i {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <!--Landing Page-->
    <div id="landing">
      <div id="landing-image">
        <i><img src="/img/diamond"></i>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!--Navigation Page-->
    <section id="navigation">

    </section>


    <!--Developer Page-->
    <section id="developer">

    </section>


    <!--Projects Page-->
    <section id="projects">

    </section>


    <!--Contact Page-->
    <section id="contact">

    </section>


  </main>
</body>
```

I want the diamond and the circle around it to be smaller and in the middle of the box on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to align the image and the circle to the center.

```
#landing-image {
  text-align: center;
}
```

For reducing size you can use **height**, **width** CSS properties for the box and the image.